# Remove file from CDN cache

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I've uploaded a file in the s3 bucket and also I've added `CDN` caching for load files. I want to update that with the same name but the problem is that I can't get updated file. `CDN` return always old file because it's cached in `CDN` for 1 year (**max-age:31536000**).

So, how can I remove it from `CDN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invalidate the file as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html. Invalidation instructs CloudFront to ignore the copy in its caches and instead contact the origin server.